# How to correctly use ResultSet with h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jdbc, database-connection, resultset

The problem is, that after displaying the `ResultSet` with `<h:dataTable>`, the connection is left open. If I close it, it closes the `ResultSet` too. I'm thinking about copying the `ResultSet` data into some `HashMap`/`ArrayList` combo. Is there a good way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you should always acquire **and** close the `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the **shortest** possible scope (preferably already inside the very same method block) and you should never pass any of them outside the DAO class. You need to map the `ResultSet` to a `List<Data>` wherein `Data` represents each row of the table. Here's a basic example how to map a resultset:

```
List<Data> items = new ArrayList<Data>();
...
while (resultSet.next()) {
    Data item = new Data();
    item.setColumn1(resultSet.getString("column1"));
    item.setColumn2(resultSet.getString("column2"));
    items.add(item);
}
...
return items;
```

Then you can just use it in the `h:dataTable`'s `value` attribute.

For more examples and insights you may find one or both of the following articles useful:
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [ResultDataSetModel](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/model/ResultSetDataModel.html)? If yes note that in javadoc stays `Note that the specified ResultSet MUST be scrollable`.

```
Statement stmt=connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Here is a complete example of [ResultDataSetModel](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-jan/o16jsf-098113.html) usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following link: http://www.coderanch.com/t/478265/JSF/java/Displaying-array-data-tables#2585794

I am sure helps you to resolve your problem